# CloudBees web app database binded

Tags: jakarta-ee, cloudbees

Is there a way to know which database is binded to your web application that is uploaded ing CloudBees using CloudBees SDK console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SDK command `bees app:bindings`. You will see both database and ecosystem bindings (newrelic, papertrail, ...)